# How to update my google cloud repository ? (facing ssh problems)

Tags: git, ssh, console, cloud

I'm facing a problem right now, whether I try to git pull, push or just clone my google cloud console repository, I get this error :

```
ssh: connect to host source.developers.google.com port 2022: Undefined error: 0
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have the right access cause I am the owner of the repository. Also, I've generated a new SSH key and added it to the "Manage SSH keys" space of the repository. I've tried several SSH keys types, still no luck.
I don't understand cause I used to update it with no issues at all, and I don't remember changing my SSH key before it happened.

Comment: `Undefined error: 0` is weird because each error has an error number, and "zero" means "worked fine, no error". So this output is saying "this failed because it worked" which makes no sense. You'll need to examine this from your OS perspective, bypassing Git entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you register your public key
   https://cloud.google.com/sourcerepositories/docs/authentication#register_a_public_key
2. Make sure you  have correct permissions for .ssh folder and keys

```
The .ssh directory permissions should be 700 (drwx------).  
The public key (.pub file) should be 644 (-rw-r--r--). 
The private key (id_rsa) on the client host.
The authorized_keys file on the server, should be 600 (-rw-------).
```

3. To debug try ssh to your repo like
   `ssh -vT myuser@source.developers.google.com`
4. Look for .ssh/config if exists and configured wrong or have one configured like below

```
host source.developers.google.com
HostName source.developers.google.com
Port 2022
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_private_key
User myuser
```